# Connect Redis Cluster with Python

Tags: python, docker, redis, bitnami, redis-cluster

I trying to connect to my redis cluster container but can't. My script is always stuck and never responds to anything every time I execute it. Here is my python script :

```
import redis

r = redis.RedisCluster(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port=36379
)

r.set('foo', 'bar')
value = r.get('foo')
print(value)
```

And here is docker compose for my redis cluster :

```
version : '3.4'

services:
  redis:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    ports:
      - 36379:6379

  redis-node-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'


  redis-node-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-3:
    # <<: *redis-common
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-4:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-5:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:7.0
    environment:
      - 'ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS=1'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR=yes'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - redis-node-1
      - redis-node-2
      - redis-node-3
      - redis-node-4
```

Does anyone here know why?

I have tried various client libraries for redis such as redis-py-cluster and redis but the result is still the same

Answer (score 1):

```
startup_nodes = [
    ('127.0.0.1', 7000),
    ('127.0.0.1', 7001),
    ('127.0.0.1', 7002),
    ('127.0.0.1', 7003)
]
rc = redis.RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes)
```

Have you tried entering nodes this way? I think you can give it a try.

Comment: Hi @levniko, thanks for the answer, but it seems that it also doesn't work and gives an error instead 
```File "/home/gumelar/learning/redis/bitnami-cluster/redis/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1401, in populate_startup_nodes
    self.startup_nodes[n.name] = n
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/41968749/does-the-redis-py-module-work-with-redis-in-cluster-mode
You can look up this I guess @gumelar